# How do I POST urlencoded form data which contains map with $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jax-rs

I am trying to send data from UI to Server through Rest call with the help of `urlencoded` form data.
I have to pass both the strings and Map as part of form data. 
I am able to pass the string values but not the map values.

Below is the code which i am using

```
customContent : function(content, contentPath, keyPath, keyValueMap){
                       console.log(keyValueMap);
                       var data = {
                             customContentId: ecpmServices.currentCustomContentId,
                             customContent: content,
                             customContentPath: contentPath,
                             keyPath: keyPath,
                             keyValueMap: keyValueMap
                       };
                       return $http({
                            url : '/ws/cpm/customContent',
                            method : 'POST',
                            data : data ,
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                                var str = [];
                                for(var p in obj)
                                {
                                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                                }
                                return str.join("&");
                            }}).then(function(res){
                                   var response = res.data;
                                   if(response.activeCustomContentId === 0) {
                                         //Some operation
                                         });
                                   }
                                });
                  }
```

In the above code keyValueMap is actually the Map and remaining are the strings.
If i see the above rest call in fiddler keyValueMap is null.
Any suggestions how to pass map data.

Comment: Can you post the content of keyValueMap (your console.log). Is it binary?

Comment: It will be something like this
{ path.here :"Here",
path.title :"Title" }

Comment: Can you please do a console.log of str.join("&") right before the return str.join("&")

Comment: "customContentId=1541&customContent=%3Ch3%3EYour%20~%5Btext%3Apsx.html.path.title%5D%20Here....%3C%2Fh3%3E&customContentPath=%2F%2Fasdf.html&keyPath=asdf&keyValueMap="

Comment: str will be something like this 
0:"customContentId=1541"
1:"customContent=%3Ch4%3EYour%20~%5Btext%3Apsx.html.path.title%5D%20Here....%3C%2Fh4%3E"
2:"customContentPath=%2F%2Fasdf.html"
3:"keyPath=asdf"
4:"keyValueMap="

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is everything all right with your script. I have even put it into a Plunker for testing:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cFU80HY9pF72YQ3ouXNN?p=preview

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {

  var send = function(content, contentPath, keyPath, keyValueMap) {
    //... here I copy pasted your function
  }

  $scope.send = function() {
    send(
      "some content here",
      "a content path",
      "a key path",
      "{key: value}"
    );
  }

}
```

It works as expected. My best guess is that the variable keyValueMap is empty at the time when you call the function. So maybe this is a timing issue - difficult to say without having the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...Data was not coming now i am able to populate the data but the problem is if you send as below 
$scope.send = function() {
    var keymap = {};
    keymap["text"] = "value";
    send(
      "some content here",
      "a content path",
      "a key path",
      keymap
    );
  }
output is coming as object object

Comment: where do you see [object object] ? In my sample you see the data string, and there is no [object object]. Can you change my sample so I see the problem?

Comment: Sorry for late reply... Can u modify the send function something like this :  $scope.send = function() { var keymap = {}; keymap["text"] = "value"; send( "some content here", "a content path", "a key path", keymap ); } in your sample, so that you will be able to see [object object] for keyvaluemap in output.

Comment: I think i got it if send the $scope.send = function() { var keymap = {}; 
   keymap["text"] = "value"; 
   send( "some content here", "a content path", "a key path", JSON.stringify(keymap) ); } something like this i will get in form of string and in server code i can typecast it to Map. Is there any other better idea?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to go - however after all this discussion: why do you want to send all your data x-www-form-urlencoded and not json?

Comment: Actually i have a very huge data to send. so preferred this rather than json.